# GWT event handling: Fire events for selective instances of listener classes

Tags: gwt

Background:

We have an application using `GWT` and the `GWTP` framework providing the `MVP` architecture. We use `GWT`'s `EventBus` to broadcast events across presenters.

Requirement:

We have an event called `RefreshEvent`. The class/presenter firing the event is `Parent(P)` and the presenter listening to this event is `Child(C)`. We are running into a situation in the application where multiple instances of the `C` (the listener) are active at the same time in the application. Let's say instance `A` and instance `B` of presenter `C` are active and both are listening for the `RefreshEvent`. But in a given context in the application I want to selectively fire the event. That is a `RefreshEvent` fired by `P` should be received only by instance `A` of `Child C` and not by instance `B` of `Child C`.

Does `GWT` provide any mechanism to do this? If not, how can I achieve this. 
Our application heavily uses events for inter presenter communication.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, EventBus is used to "broadcast" an event to each party that listens to it (in your example, all instances of your Child C).

If you want a single relationship, your parent can simply call the necessary child:

```
private Child a;
private Child b;
...
public void on onRefresh() {
    /*
     *  If you need to call child a, call a.doSomething();
     *  If you need to call child b, call b.doSomething();
     */
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. The issue here is that the parent class does not have reference to the instance of the listener child class.

Comment: Give it a reference. That will be like registering for an event.